# How to inject prototype bean in Spring AuthenticationSuccessHandler implementation

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-security

I am using Spring security AuthenticationSuccessHandler for my login validation.

```
@Component
public class LoginAuthenticationHandler  implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
….
```

I am injecting UserData in LoginAuthenticationHandler, as follows

```
@Autowired
UserData userData;
```

UserData should be prototype.

When I print the hash code of userData inside LoginAuthenticationHandler for different users [at the user login time] the hash code is same. It tells me UserData bean is not working as prototype.

This is the LoginAuthenticationHandler definition from spring-security.xml

```
<beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.org.login.handler.LoginAuthenticationHandler" scope="prototype">
</beans:bean>
```

This is the UserData bean class

```
@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class UserDataImpl implements UserData {
```

What is the option to make the UserData a ‘real’ prototype

Comment: Actually it is working as a prototype. You get a new instance for each time you request a new instance. However the only new instance created is at startup time. Injecting a prototype into a singleton creates a specific instance for that singleton bean. If you would inject the `UserData` into 2 different beans you would get 2 instances. In shor tdon't autowire if you want it a to behave like a prototype do a look up, or maybe use a request scoped bean instead. Which still gives the same hashcode but then for a dynamic proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have defined your LoginAuthenticationHandler bean twice (annotation and XML), don't do that.

When you want to use a prototype bean inside a singleton bean, you must use a proxy. Alter your scope annotation:

```java
@Scope(value="prototype", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are both annotating your `LoginAuthenticationHandler` with `@Component`, making it an auto-discovered Spring bean, and declaring it in XML configuration. The bean created by annotation will be a singleton, and the one created from XML will be a prototype. You haven't shown how you actually use that bean, but it stands to reason that the rest of the system is using the singleton version. Of course, that version has its single instance of `UserData` assigned once, upon the creation of the singleton.

To move forward first clear up the situation with the declaration of `LoginAuthenticationHandler`.